# I am Unable to Upload the APK in Play Consol

Tags: androidexported

Issue: You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle which has an activity, activity alias, service, or broadcast receiver with intent filter, but without the 'android: exported' property set. This file can't be installed on Android 12 or higher. See developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#exported
I have Already Entered the **android:exported="true" ** But It is Showing the Same

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    android:installLocation="auto"
    android:compileSdkVersion="31"
    android:compileSdkVersionCodename="12"
    package="com.fm.localdukan"
    platformBuildVersionCode="31"
    platformBuildVersionName="12"
    android:exported="true"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <permission
        android:name="io.kodular.localdukan_in.LOCAL_DUKAN_2.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="io.kodular.localdukan_in.LOCAL_DUKAN_2.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.sonyericsson.home.permission.BROADCAST_BADGE" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.htc.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="29" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="me.everything.badger.permission.BADGE_COUNT_READ" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.WRITE" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.READ" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.anddoes.launcher.permission.UPDATE_COUNT" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.oppo.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.READ_APP_BADGE" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.CHANGE_BADGE" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.majeur.launcher.permission.UPDATE_BADGE" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.sonymobile.home.permission.PROVIDER_INSERT_BADGE" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.htc.launcher.permission.UPDATE_SHORTCUT" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="me.everything.badger.permission.BADGE_COUNT_WRITE" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.oppo.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS" />
    <application
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:label="Local Dukan"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:name="com.google.appinventor.components.runtime.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
        android:debuggable="false"
        android:supportsRtl="false"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:preserveLegacyExternalStorage="true">
        <activity
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:name="io.kodular.localdukan_in.LOCAL_DUKAN_2.Screen2"
            android:exported="true"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:name="io.kodular.localdukan_in.LOCAL_DUKAN_2.Screen1"
            android:exported="true"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="io.kodular.app.VERSION"
            android:value="1.5B.3-Fenix" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="onesignal_app_id"
            android:value="b399ac27-1ba0-4b68-b362-fa0c91e59ec8" />
        <receiver
            android:name="com.onesignal.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter
                android:priority="999">
                <action
                    android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category
                    android:name="io.kodular.localdukan_in.LOCAL_DUKAN_2" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.onesignal.NotificationOpenedReceiver" />
        <service
            android:name="com.onesignal.GcmIntentService" />
        <service
            android:name="com.onesignal.GcmIntentJobService"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />
        <service
            android:name="com.onesignal.RestoreJobService"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />
        <service
            android:name="com.onesignal.RestoreKickoffJobService"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />
        <service
            android:name="com.onesignal.SyncService"
            android:stopWithTask="false" />
        <service
            android:name="com.onesignal.SyncJobService"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />
        <activity
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
            android:name="com.onesignal.PermissionsActivity"
            android:exported="true" /=>
        <service
            android:name="com.onesignal.NotificationRestoreService" />
        <receiver
            android:name="com.onesignal.BootUpReceiver"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.onesignal.UpgradeReceiver"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <activity
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity"
            android:exported="true" />
        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service
            android:name="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentDiscoveryService">
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.iid.Registrar"
                android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthRegistrar"
                android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.abt.component.AbtRegistrar"
                android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.analytics.connector.internal.AnalyticsConnectorRegistrar"
                android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.remoteconfig.RemoteConfigRegistrar"
                android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
        </service>
        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:exported="true"
            android:authorities="com.fm.localdukan.provider"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>
        <uses-library
            android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
            android:required="true" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```